# Caesar cipher code not working properly C

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I've been working on a Caesar cipher problem for a problem set but I ran into a minor problem.
Whenever the cipher value gets more the the ascii of 'z', I want it to bounce back to 'a' but I'm not able to figure out how to do so.
Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc !=2 && !isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //convert input to int and get the string
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    k=k%26;
    //printf("%d" ,k);
    //get he text

    char *s;
    s=GetString();
    int i, n=strlen(s);

    //checking each character
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==' ')
        {
            s[i]=' ';
        }
        else
        {
            s[i]=s[i]+k;
        }
        printf("%c" ,s[i]);
    }

}
```

This is quite a basic code. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. here is an example with key 4.

```
input-  Vinay Dawani
output- Zmre} He{erm
```

Comment: What should happen with `z` and `Z` when the key is 4?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  There are a lot of questions about Caesar cipher implementations on SO.  Most of them would show you ways in which to solve your problem.  You really take a look at (some of) them.  It doesn't look as if you've tried to deal with the problem at all — you're just aware that you've got it.  You should show what you've tried.  (Also, at some point you'll have to decide what to do with digits and punctuation.  At the moment, you're treating them like letters, which probably isn't the best choice.)

Comment: Give a look in this snippet: _http://ideone.com/QwOl1s_

Comment: Hint : `k=k%26;` "bounces back" `k`.  To bounce back to `a`, use similar code.

Comment: `isdigit(argv[1])` is not  valid code.  `isdigit()` is for single charaters,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code set in use is not [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (which has non-alphabetic characters in between alphabetic characters), then letters of the Latin alphabet (unaccented a-z) are coded as contiguous code points in all the common code sets.  The rotation of the alphabet is simple when you know how.

Fundamentally, you convert each letter into an offset 0..25 from the letter `a` or `A` (depending on case), add the encoding key, take the result modulo 26, and add the starting letter (`a` or `A`) back.  Note that the arithmetic takes place as `int`, but the result is assigned back to a (possibly signed) `char`.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || !isdigit((unsigned char)argv[1][0]))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s shift\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // convert input to int and get the string
    int k = atoi(argv[1]) % 26;
    if (k < 0)
        k += 26;

    char *s = GetString();
    int n = strlen(s);

    printf("Original:  [%s]\n", s);

    // encoding each character
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isupper((unsigned char)s[i]))
        {
            s[i] = 'A' + (s[i] - 'A' + k) % 26;
        }
        else if (islower((unsigned char)s[i]))
        {
            s[i] = 'a' + (s[i] - 'a' + k) % 26;
        }
    }

    printf("Encrypted: [%s]\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./caesar13 3
Caesar's cipher is hardly secure against the lazy dog jumping over the quick brown fox, is it?
Original:  [Caesar's cipher is hardly secure against the lazy dog jumping over the quick brown fox, is it?]
Encrypted: [Fdhvdu'v flskhu lv kdugob vhfxuh djdlqvw wkh odcb grj mxpslqj ryhu wkh txlfn eurzq ira, lv lw?]
$ ./caesar50 23
Fdhvdu'v flskhu lv kdugob vhfxuh djdlqvw wkh odcb grj mxpslqj ryhu wkh txlfn eurzq ira, lv lw?
Original:  [Fdhvdu'v flskhu lv kdugob vhfxuh djdlqvw wkh odcb grj mxpslqj ryhu wkh txlfn eurzq ira, lv lw?]
Encrypted: [Caesar's cipher is hardly secure against the lazy dog jumping over the quick brown fox, is it?]
$
```

The [CS50 library](https://manual.cs50.net/library/) is readily available online.

Comment: EBCDIC is still a thing? But most of the world uses characters outside of the letters of the Latin alphabet (unaccented a-z).

Comment: @zaph:  It depends on the machines you work on.  Mostly "no", but IBM mainframes or systems related to them can still use EBCDIC.  It's mainly a caution that the value of `'z' - 'a'` is not guaranteed to be 25, though it is, by far, the most common value.  It's a CMA comment — the code is OK provided the native code set is not EBCDIC.  I suppose I could add an assertion such as `assert('z' - 'a' == 25);` or a static assertion such as `_Static_assert('z' - 'a' == 25, "Code set does not support contiguous alphabet");` somewhere in the code.

Answer (score -1):

After you add `k` to the letter, check if it's higher than `z`. If it is, just subtract the number of letters in the alphabet to wrap it around.

```
s[i] = s[i]+k;
if (s[i] > 'z') {
    s[i] = s[i] - 26;
}
```

to deal with upper and lower case, you need separate tests in the main loop.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(islower(s[i]))
    {
        s[i] += k;
        if (s[i] > 'z') {
            s[i] -= 26;
        }
    }
    else if (isupper(s[i]))
    {
        s[i] += k;
        if (s[i] > 'Z') {
            s[i] -= 26;
        }
    }
    printf("%c" ,s[i]);
}
```

Notice that I removed the test for `if (s[i] == ' ')`. That's not necessary -- anything that isn't a letter is simply left alone.

Comment: but @Barmar, this code is only good if i just want to change small letters..what about capitals?

Comment: Perhaps simpler would be to modulo by 26 after the addition.  Ie: s [i]=(s[I]+k)%26.

Comment: Use different cases in your `if()` for `islower(s[i])` and `isupper(s[i])`. Then you can compare with `z` and `Z`.

Comment: @RobertBaron It doesn't account for the fact that letter values start at 65 and 97.

Comment: What happens if the key is, say, 20, and you need to encrypt 'z' and you're machine has plain `char` as a signed type?

Comment: I am just confused.

Comment: then @JonathanLeffler it will display the character with ascii 142 i.e. Ä

Comment: @VinayDawani: There are a number of problems with your comment "it will display the character with ascii 142 i.e. Ä", such as: "ASCII only goes from 0 to 127" (so it isn't really ASCII), and "since the question I asked stipulated plain `char` is signed, the value would be negative", and "in ISO 8859-n, code point 0x8E (aka 142) is a C1 control character (ISO/IEC 6429:1992), not a printing letter".  In Windows CP1252 (CP1250), the letter is U+017D LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON, Ž, I believe, which is not the same as U+00C4 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS.